# Find the average square distance in multivariable calculus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the average square distance from the origin to a point in D = $\{(x,y)|y^2 +1 \le x \le 3\}$.

How to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the distance from the origin of an arbitrary point we have $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  So the square of the distance is just $x^2+y^2$.

Integrating over $D$ gives you the total distance from the origin.  The multivariable analog to the length of an interval is the area of a region.  So the double integral over that region will give you the are of region.  Dividing the total distance by the area will give you the average distance.

$$\frac{\iint(x^2+y^2)dA}{\iint dA}$$

Comment: for the numerator, i put integral bounds as int 0 to 3 int 0 to sqrt (x-1) dy dx. Would this work or the other way round (int 0 to squrt(2) int 3 to (y^2 + 1 dx dy) be better?

Comment: Since you have $x$ bounds in terms of $y$ you would need to integrate $dxdy$.  If you do it the other way you have to remember that $y$ can be negative.